# Поиск нескольких слов в тексте

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст например:

```
Батарея не очень горячая
```

Есть массив:

```
$array = array('очень', 'горячая', 'батарея');
```

Как реализовать так, что бы условие с `preg_match` срабатывало тогда, когда именно эти 3 слова из массива присутствуют в тексте, даже если не по порядку?

Answer (score 3):

А зачем вам регулярки для этой цели? Можно использовать strpos()

```
function check_string($str, $words)
{
    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        if(strpos($str, $word) !== false)
            continue;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
$str = 'Батарея не очень гарячая';
$words = array('очень', 'гарячая', 'батарея');
if(check_string($str,$words))
    echo "Все слова содержатся в строке";
else
    echo "Не все слова содержатся в строке";
```

Comment: добавлю, что если все же есть нужда в регулярных выражениях (ну мало ли, может пример был приведен для упрощения задачи), то решение будет аналогичным, только вместо strpos() использовать preg_match(), т.к. задать в регулярном выражении слова, которые могут идти в разном порядке и при этом обязательно встречаться все сразу не получится (разве что через ретроспективную и опережающую проверки), все равно придется проверять, сколько их встретилось уже после выполнения preg_match() или preg_match_all()

Comment: @MDJHD У меняя еще вопрос, strpos работает с числами? просто почему то он если 2 числа в $words, берет только 1

Comment: @foozzi, не совсем понял про числа, можно поподробнее описать проблему. Также как вариант, в мануале написано про второй параметр ф-и strpos:

    int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
    needle 
Если needle не является строкой, он приводится к целому и трактуется как **код символа**.